# CSS hover and active selection for UL

Tags: css

Hi I have different colors for hover and active menu items. The problem is that when an item is active it changes color when hovered. I want it to maintain its active color. I mean I don't want the hover color to apply to an active menu item.

CSS:

```
li a:hover{ 
   color: black; 
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px black;
}

li.active a{ 
   color: #f37121; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: No, the color doesn't change with you current css - http://jsfiddle.net/2ta62obL/

Comment: @sdcr I believe he means the text shadow

Answer (score 0):

You can add inheritance to active link.

Just adding:

```
li.active a:hover{ color: inherit;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `:not(selector)`. This matches every element that isn't `selector`.

You just need to add this into your first rule for `li`.

```
li:not(.active) a:hover{ color: black; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px black;}
```

Run the snippet below:

```css
li:not(.active) a:hover{ color: black; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px black;}
li.active a { color: #f37121; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px;}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">inactive link 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">active link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inactive link 2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) (CCS3 selectors are [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) nowerdays) to specify you only want the changes to happen on anchor tags that do not have the `.active` class

```
li:not(.active) a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srqnuyp7/3/

Or you could simply add `text-shadow:none;` as an additional rule

```
li.active a {
    text-shadow:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srqnuyp7/2/